# How to parse through a .txt file in the Classify function and assign a class to each item?

Tags: import, machine-learning

I have 2 txt files that contain 500 DNA sequences each. Both files use 2 hard returns to separate the sequences like so:

```
ATCGATCT...

ATCGATCT...

ATCGATCT...
```

I want to parse these two files into the Classify function such that each item in the txt file is assigned a class, `Gene1` and `Gene2`. I have already separated the two classes of DNA in their respective txt files.

Because of this, I was thinking I can classify all the items in `txt1` as `Gene1` and all the items in `txt2` as `Gene2`. As for how to do this, I am not sure. Does Mathematica allow parsing of items from a txt file into the Classify function?

I was hoping it would be a simple line of code such as this:

```
c = Classify[{Import["txt1.txt"]} -> "Gene1", {Import["txt2.txt"]} -> "Gene2"]
```

Comment: How about ``c = Classify[Join@@Map[Thread[StringSplit[Import["txt"<>#<>".txt"], "\n"]-> "Gene"<>#]&, ToString/@Range[2]]]``?

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was wondering if you could explain what the `<>#` symbols in `[Import["txt" <> # <> ".txt"], "\n"] -> "Gene" <> #] &, 
 ToString /@ Range[2]]` means. Also, why are you using `@Range[2]`?

Comment: `<>` is Mathematica shorthand for `StringJoin` and `#` is shorthand for `Slot` in a `Function` (worth looking all these terms up in the docs as understanding them will be very helpful moving forward). Pro-tip: you can select a symbol and use Command-Shift-F (or Control-F1 on Windows) to look up what it does.

Comment: Hey b3m, I've been trying out the code you provided in its different components and I've been getting stuck at the import part. Specifically, I don't understand `Import["txt"<>#<>".txt"], "\n"]`. Does `"\n"` tell the function that **1** hard enter signifies the separation between each item in the txt file? I am also not sure where I input the filepath for the 2 txt files. I thought I enter the filepaths in the `"txt"`sections like so `Import["C:\\filepath\\test1.txt"<>#<>"C:\\filepath\\test2.txt"]`, but this gives me a `File not found during import` error. Thank you for your help in advance!